# "npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack " in OSX

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ubuntu

I tried to setup MEAN stack where I required angular to be installed. When I tried this command "`npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack`", I ended up with following error in terminal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl51N.png)

Comment: Don't do this , Please paste error body here!

Answer (score 0):

No Need to install fullstack for angular js. you can simply go with installation of angular like `npm install angular` and include dependency in your respective index.html file
You can use [this link for refernace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular)